# is TCP hole punching practical for this?

Tags: rest, networking, tcp, proxy, hole-punching

This project is a bit similar to a home automation project so keep home automation in mind.

- I have a Globally Accessible Server known as `S`
- There is a mobile client known as `M`
- There is a hub known as `H`

Since a lot of IP's are dynamic and ISP's charge extra costs for static IP's and having customers to port forward their ports for my applications is impractical.

I've heard that TCP Hole punching for P2P can be unreliable, However using `S` as a proxy for all requests seems impractical as there would be a huge load on `S`.

### My Goal:

Connect `M` to `H` so they can make RESTful HTTP Requests to eachother.

### My Questions

1. How would I manage a situation where neither `M` or `H` can initiate a connection via TCP? (use UDP?)
2. If TCP Hole punching doesn't work in the situation, could I send UDP packs instead? (UDP's are unreliable in terms of delivery, so would sending multiple duplicate packets guarantee delivery?)

### Notes

I know generally how hole punching works, `S` must give the endpoints of both clients to eachother so they can both try initiate a connection. and I also have a good understanding of NAT's

Maybe for the rarer cases that TCP Hole Punching is ineffective, `S` could act as a proxy

Comment: Define "hub". How is a "hub" different from a server? Why can't M initiate a TCP connection to "H"?

Comment: The hub is practically a server yes, however it's not globally accessible `M` Doesn't know the endpoint of `H`. 

Both `M` & `H` have to initiate connections or Hole punching won't work, could you elaborate on what you meant?

Comment: If I understand your question, it is very rare to try to allow H to make a TCP connection to M, where H acts as a TCP client (it sends the SYN packet) and M acts as a TCP server. The usual solution is to always have M make the connections, perhaps using some polling scheme or using the mobile client's native push notification service to reduce power consumption on the mobile.

Comment: I don't think you understand how Hole punching works. `H` and `M` MUST both send packets to initiate connection, if only `M` or `H` sends a packet, it will be blocked by the firewall and the other side won't realise it was sent a packet.

Comment: `M` will always initiate the connection by asking `S` for `H`'s endpoint AND telling `H` to send packets to `M`. If that's what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

> 1. How would I manage a situation where neither M or H can initiate a
>      connection via TCP? (use UDP?)

Yes via UDP. Or using TCP through S.

> 2. If TCP Hole punching doesn't work in the situation, could I send UDP
>      packs instead? (UDP's are unreliable in terms of delivery, so would
>      sending multiple duplicate packets guarantee delivery?)

It depends. You have to have checks on receiver side which will determine if the packet is received or not and then send a notification to the sender. Because you may send 10/20 same packets and still they may not reach the receiver. But if you want to have reliable packet delivery and also UDP then there is a protocol called [RUDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reliable_User_Datagram_Protocol).

**Note that** whether you use TCP or UDP, you can't always establish P2P connection successfully. Many of the time you must make connection through S or you fail to connect. The scenario is if one of the end point has Symmetric NAT and other has PRC/Symmetric NAT. Now a days many of the LTE based connection uses Symmetric NAT.